# Cannot test if emit is called in Vue 3 component

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, testing-library

In my Vue 3 component I have a link that uses `@click.prevent` to call a method that emits and event. I'm unable to figure out why my attempts to test if this method is called or event is emitted fail.

Component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits<{
  closeMinicart: any[];
}>();

const closeDialog = (ev: Event) => {
  console.log('------------- close dialog ----------------');
  emit('closeMinicart');
};
</script>
<template>
  <a
   href="#"
   @click.prevent="closeDialog($event)">
    Continue shopping
  </a>
</template>
```

Test:

```
it('should emit `closeDialog` when clicked', async () => {
 const user = userEvent.setup();
 const { emitted } = render(EmptyCart);
 const el = screen.getByText(/Continue shopping/i);
 await user.click(el);
 await waitFor(() => {
   expect(emitted()).toHaveProperty('closeMinicart');
 })
});
```

It fails with this message:

```
 FAIL  src/components/EmptyCart.test.ts > Continue shopping link > should emit `closeDialog` when clicked
AssertionError: expected { pointerover: [ [ …(1) ] ], …(11) } to have property "closeMinicart"
```

But the `console.log` inside the function is always printed out in the terminal.

I've tried using the plain vue-test-utils with `mount` and adding `wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` but that doesn't work for me either.

I tried changing the link to a button as well as removing the `.prevent` (putting `preventDefault` in the method) but they don't work either.

I also attempted to create a `spy` on the `closeDialog` method like so:

```
it('...', () => {
//...
const spy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'closeDialog');
//...
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But I kept getting errors talking about not being able to call a spy on undefined or something similar.

**Edit**

An even more bare-bones example. Making my component look like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from 'vue';

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'myEvent'): void;
  (e: 'foobar', value: string): void;
}>();

onMounted(() => {
  emit('foobar', 'something to talk about');
});
</script>
<template>
  <a href="#"
     @click.prevent="$emit('myEvent')">
     Continue shopping
  </a>
</template>
```

With this test:

```
it('should emit `myEvent` when clicked', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent);
  expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('foobar');
  await wrapper.find('a').trigger('click');
  expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('myEvent');
});
```

I get:

```
AssertionError: expected { click: [ [ …(1) ] ] } to have property "foobar"
```

If I console.log JSON.stringify emitted, it returns this:

```
{"click":[[{"isTrusted":false,"_vts":1691539798806}]]}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Otherwise, could you show us a little bit more of what your test looks like?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this yet. There isn't anything else to show in the test for the second/edit example. The only things I've left out of it are the standard imports and the `describe` block.